# Query Between to dates not collecting correct rows

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

In the query below i have 5 tables a depicted in my crude ERD. The query is meant to select the homes from the Homes table and its features and type from the corresponding tables. The bit i am having trouble is with selecting the homes that dont exist in the bookings table between a specific date range input into the query.

```
 Bookings  >--  Home  >--  Home_Type
                  |
                  ^
            Home_Feature
                  V
                  |
               Feature


SELECT homes.home_id, 
    homes.title, 
    homes.description, 
    homes.living_room_count, 
    homes.bedroom_count, 
    homes.bathroom_count, 
    homes.price, homes.sqft,
    listagg(features.feature_name, '\n') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY features.feature_name) features, 
    home_type.type_name
FROM homes
INNER JOIN home_feature 
  ON homes.home_id = home_feature.home_id
INNER JOIN home_type 
  ON home_type.type_code = homes.type_code
INNER JOIN features 
  ON home_feature.feature_id = features.feature_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT home_id
                  FROM bookings b
                  WHERE b.home_id = homes.home_id 
                  AND (b.booking_end <= to_date('25-Jan-13') OR b.booking_end >= to_date('21-Jan-13'))
                  AND (b.booking_start <= to_date('25-Jan-13') OR b.booking_start >= to_date('21-Jan-13')))
GROUP BY homes.home_id, homes.title, 
    homes.description, homes.living_room_count, 
    homes.bedroom_count, homes.bathroom_count, 
    homes.price, homes.sqft, home_type.type_name
```

Now at the moment my query doesn't seem to be be correctly getting the correct rows. An example output at the moment is below along with what is currently in the bookings table and you can see that the incorrect rows are being returned.

Output:

```
Home_ID    Title    Description    LivingRooms    Bedrooms    Bathrooms    Price    SQFT    Type    Features
3          Home A   A House        2              2           2            200      500     Flat    TV...
4          Home B   B House        3              1           1            250      600     House   Pool...
```

Booking Table:

```
Home_ID    Booking_ID    Customer_ID    Booking_Start    Booking_End
1          1             1              22-Jan-13        23-Jan-13
2          2             3              27-Jan-13        29-Jan-13
```

Homes Table:

```
Home_ID    ....
1          ....
2
3           
4
```

Clearly the output from the query at the moment should also be including Home_ID 2 but is not, but im under the impression that the query should work?

The query at the moment SHOULD look like this:

```
Home_ID    Title    Description    LivingRooms    Bedrooms    Bathrooms    Price    SQFT    Type    Features
2          Home 2   2 House        3              1           1            100      300     Flat    Balcony...
3          Home 3   3 House        2              2           2            200      500     Flat    TV...
4          Home 4   4 House        3              1           1            250      600     House   Pool...
```

Can anyone help me modify the query so as to work and include the correct rows?

Comment: Are there any rows for home_id 2 in home_feature? If there aren't, the inner join will exclude that id before the WHERE clause gets a chance. Also, the WHERE clause in the subquery, `WHERE b.home_id = homes.home_id` is probably *not* doing what you think it's doing. Test *without* that WHERE clause.

Comment: Yeah, theres a couple rows of Home_ID 2 in Home_Feature

Comment: @user1851487, Maybe you should care to create tables and data first and post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `left outer join` instead of the `where not exists`.

Try this:

```
...
INNER JOIN features 
  ON home_feature.feature_id = features.feature_id
left outer join bookings b
  on homes.home_id = b.home_id
where (
        (b.booking_end <= to_date('25-Jan-13')
         OR b.booking_end >= to_date('21-Jan-13')
        )
        AND
        (b.booking_start <= to_date('25-Jan-13')
         OR b.booking_start >= to_date('21-Jan-13')
        )
      )
      or b.home_id is null
...
```

This will return homes without a booking (`or b.home_id is null`) and homes with a booking that matches your condition.

This should now return all four homes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But home_id 1 shouldn't be in the query results because its booked out between those 2 dates.

Comment: @user1851487: In that case your where condition is wrong. The first part says: "The end date has to be less than 25/1/13 OR greater than 21/1/13". Your end date is 23/1/13, which satisfies both conditions: It is greater than 21/1/13 and less than 25/1/13. The second part says: "The start date has to be less than 25/1/13 OR greater than 21/1/13". Your start date is 22/1/13, which again satisifies both conditions. I think you want the following condition: The end date should be less than 21/1/13 or the start date should be greater than 25/1/13

Comment: thanks, i changed the where condition as suggested and it fixed it. Thanks for your help.